# How to check if gcc has failed, returned a warning, or succeeded in Bash?

Tags: bash, gcc

How would I go about checking whether gcc has succeeded in compiling a program, failed, or succeeded but with a warning?

```
#!/bin/sh

string=$(gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld)

if [ string -n ]; then
    echo "Failure"
else
    echo "Success!"
fi
```

This only checks whether it has succeeded or (failed or compiled with warnings).

-n means "is not null".

Thanks!

**EDIT** If it's not clear, this isn't working.

Comment: Another reason why it can't possibly work: the correct syntax is `[ -n "$string" ]`.

Comment: Note that gcc will return an exit code of 0 even when warnings are presented.

Comment: If warnings must be taken into account -Werror can help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld; then 
echo "Success!";
else 
echo "Failure"; 
fi
```

You want bash to test the return code, not the output. Your code captures stdout, but ignores the value returned by GCC (ie the value returned by main()).

Comment: Alternatively, run gcc in a separate shell script line, then test $?.

Comment: This doesn't distinguish "returned with a warning".

Answer (score 21):

Your condition should be:

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
```

GCC will return zero on success, or something else on failure.  That line says "if the last command returned something other than zero."

Comment: $? means return value of last ran command if anyone doesn't know

Comment: [Why is testing `$?` to see if a command succeeded or not an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 12):

To tell the difference between compiling completely cleanly and compiling with errors, first compile normally and test $?. If non-zero, compiling failed. Next, compile with the -Werror (warnings are treated as errors) option. Test $? - if 0, it compiled without warnings. If non-zero, it compiled with warnings.

Ex:

```
gcc -Wall -o foo foo.c
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Compile failed!"
    exit 1
fi

gcc -Wall -Werror -o foo foo.c
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Compile succeeded, but with warnings"
    exit 2
else
    echo "Compile succeeded without warnings"
fi
```

Comment: This brute forcing includes two compilations. If you really want to go that way the second run should include `-fsyntax-only` (there won't be anything more than parsing the complete code).
In any case the option to additional check `gcc`s output (storing its stdout in a temporary file and grep for `arning` [the w may be in uppercase or not]) is likely the better solution.

Comment: `if ! gcc -Wall -o foo foo.c; then echo "Compile failed!"; exit 1; fi` -- no reason to use `$?` at all. `[ $? -eq 0 ]` is generating a _second_ `$?` (that of the `[` command) and testing that; why not just test the `$?` of the `gcc` command directly?