# Can gcc return a value?

Tags: gcc

How can I know the return value of gcc?

For example, I have one c file, test.c, and I simply run `gcc test.c` in terminal. It can report if current compile meet some errors, but how can I know the return value of this time compile process of gcc?

Now I know `1` means has error, but `0` will return not only warning but also compile OK, how can I if there is error. If I use `-Werror`, it may stop compile, I don't want to stop compile

Comment: Related: [How to check if gcc has failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024525/how-to-check-if-gcc-has-failed-returned-a-warning-or-succeeded-in-bash)

Comment: I add some warning in code and use gcc to compile:`>gcc -Wall test.c 
test.c:3:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5:6: warning: unused variable ‘noUse’ [-Wunused-variable]` and I use `echo $?`., it return as `>echo $?
0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return variable is in the shell variable `$?`.

```
> gcc bla.c
> echo $?
0
```

Edit: on windows it is in [%errorlevel%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line).

Comment: I test it, but it seems warning will return 0 as well, I just add `-Wall` when use gcc and add an unused value in my source code, gcc generate warning but return 0