# Makefile error message custom

Tags: bash, error-handling, makefile

I have some problem with a makefile.
I just want to test if the compilation on src/launcher.c failed or not.
But before that, i just can't convert this bash code:

```
out=$(gcc -c src/launcher.c -o /obj/launcher.o 2>&1)
```

To "Makefile code"

in fact, i want to make something like that :
[Handling gcc warnings and output in a Bash Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287903/handling-gcc-warnings-and-output-in-a-bash-script)
but in a makefile

Please, if you have some ideas.

```
CC      = clang
RM      = rm -f

NAME        = automakefile

CFLAGS      += -Wall -Wextra
CFLAGS      += -O2 -march=native -fomit-frame-pointer

LDFLAGS     +=

OBJS_DIR    = ./obj/
SRCS_DIR    = ./src/

INCLUDES    += -I ./src/include

OBJS_FILES  = launcher.o

OBJS        = $(foreach obj,$(OBJS_FILES),$(OBJS_DIR)$(obj))

all: script $(NAME)

script:
    @if [ ! -d "$(OBJS_DIR)" ]; then    \
        mkdir $(OBJS_DIR);      \
    fi

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(NAME) $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJS_DIR)%.o: $(SRCS_DIR)%.c
    //This line isn't working!
    $(eval TMP=$$(gcc -c src/launcher.c -o obj/launcher.o 2>&1))
    echo $(TMP)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.Phony: all script clean fclean re
```

Thanks
Have a nice day

Comment: The "if" is testing the status of the echo, which is always true.

Comment: I remove the if for no confusion, because it's not the main problem. I need to convert the bash on the top

Comment: Sorry, i update that...

Answer (score 1):

Make will automatically stop the compilation process whenever an error occur, but you can do with a message in case of warning or nothing bad happened:

```
$(OBJS_DIR)%.o: $(SRCS_DIR)%.c
    @$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< &>output
    @if grep "warning" output >/dev/null ; then echo "$(<F) Warning" ; else echo "$(<F) OK" ; fi
    @$(RM) output
```

---

Here you go:

```
$(OBJS_DIR)%.o: $(SRCS_DIR)%.c
    @if $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< &>output; then \
        if grep "warning" output >/dev/null; then              \
            echo "$(<F) Warning(s)";                           \
        else                                                   \
            echo "$(<F) OK";                                   \
        fi;                                                    \
    else                                                       \
        echo "$(<F) Error(s)";                                 \
    fi
    @$(RM) output
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for you answer. So you think that it's just impossible to do something like in the link above into a makefile?

Comment: You could get the whole compilation process out of the makefile, which would then call that script instead.

Comment: @EtanReisner It was a remnant of my previous experiments, it has now been removed.

Comment: @user3409642 I think I got it now.

Comment: Yes, i don't like the tmp file. But i ended like this too

Answer (score 1):

make stops on target failure, you won't get any farther than the compilation that fails so you won't see anything beyond that.

If you are looking to "silence" the compilation a bit (so you don't see the compilation command itself) you could look into using something like my [silent make rules](https://github.com/deryni/silent-make-rules) makefile (based on the silencing support in recent autotools).

That won't hide output from the compilation commands themselves (warnings, etc.) but for successful/warning-free compilation there shouldn't be much output anyway and for failures/warnings you likely want to see it.

If you *do* want to do something like in your original link then you need to make sure that you hide the error code return from `gcc` in an `if` or similar (and capture it) and then exit with it again at the end of the recipe so that make still stops correctly.

Comment: @user3409642 I haven't written any introduction/help for that yet, if you can't figure it out feel free to ask or file an issue or something.

Answer (score 1):

At the end, i used a little trick:

```
@$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(INCLUDES) \
                && echo -e "\033[33;1m=== Compilation $@ \tSUCCEED===\033[0m"\
                || echo -e "\033[1;31m=== Compilation $@ \tFAILED===\033[0m"
```