# How to integrate other language compilers to Java Project?

Tags: java, compilation

I'm involved on a university project that consist on doing a Web. 
This project has many items and one of the most difficult of them is the one that I'm asking here. 
In the web, there are problems where the users have to submit code solving them. And the web should return if the code is operative or not. To do this I need to integrate different compilers of different languages like python, c++ and many others.
The fact is that I don't know how to integrate this compilers on my code, or how to pick the text entered on the web and send it to a online compiler web to pick the results and compare to the solutions. 
I wonder if someone has any idea of how to do it.
Thanks

Comment: maybe you are looking for JNI.

Comment: Please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. This request is way too broad, it simply can't be answered sufficiently with a single answer. As the answer is: you have a ton of work in front of you. It starts with the fact: do you really consider it *wise* to accept any kind of C++ code, compile and run that on your server? What if there is code making a system call to do a "rm -rf *" ? As said: this is much larger than you think it is, and you should rather talk to your peers in that project to *first* come up with a reasonable overall design.

Answer (score 0):

If you *just* need to compile code, you could:

1. Accept the text input from your web site.
2. Save that input as a file.
3. Use the `Process` class to call on the compilers for the language you want through console. You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024525/how-to-check-if-gcc-has-failed-returned-a-warning-or-succeeded-in-bash) previous SO question for guidance. You might want to create your own wrappers (other bash scripts) which in turn call the compiler and do the processing of the compiler result.

Comment: There is no "just" here ... this is a really complicated undertaking

Comment: @GhostCat: Yeah I know, which is why I marked *just* in Italics in my answer --> I was oversimplifying.